# Non-linear waves and solitons: verifying solution for Nonlinear Schrödinger Equation

Tags: matrix-equations, inverse-problems, soliton-theory

> If the initial solution is the unstable background $(2),$ the corresponding fundamental solution of the Lax pair is \begin{align*}\Psi_0(\lambda)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\mu(\mu+\lambda)}}\,e^{it\sigma_3}\left[\begin{matrix}e^{\Theta(\lambda)} &-(\mu+\lambda)e^{-\Theta(\lambda)}\\(\mu+\lambda)e^{\Theta(\lambda)}&e^{-\Theta(\lambda)}\end{matrix}\right],\qquad (36)\\  \Theta(\lambda)&\equiv i\mu(x+2\lambda t), \end{align*} where $\sigma_3=\operatorname{diag}(1, -1)$ is the Pauli matrix and $\mu, \lambda$ are complex parameters satisfying the constraint $$\mu^2=1+\lambda^2.\qquad (37)$$ **EsRW 05.** Verify that $(36)$ is the fundamental solution of $(4)$ corresponding to $(2),$ and satisfying $\det(\Psi_0)=1.$

I'm verifying the Nonlinear Schrödinger equation using the Zakharov-Shabat (ZS) Lax pair condition. I've almost finished but I can't solve this last thing.
The last equation has three matrices with the same determinant, so I thought to diagonalize them in order to find the solution, which is $\mu^2=1+\lambda^2.$
Could you help me to find that please?

Ok, I'm going to post the entire exercise, I hope I am clear this time! Thank for your help!

[image: This is the first page of the exercise]
[image: This is the second page of the exercise]

Comment: It would also be good to report what you got for $\psi,$ please!

Comment: Also, could you please show the relationships among $t, x,$ and $\theta?$ I did my dissertation on this stuff, so I'd love to help you out!

Comment: Thank you guys, you can see all you need here:      http://www.roma1.infn.it/people/santini/Didattica3/darboux_NLS_RW.pdf       the exercise is the number Es.Rw 05

Comment: Sorry, that's a bad link for me.

Comment: ok, i'll make some screenshot

Comment: ok, i've re-edited my post with the screenshot!

Comment: Your working is still cut off - I've typed up your problem statement. But you need to either type up your working, or re-post a better scan of the remaining link. You should also tell us what Equation $(4)$ is.

Comment: Dear Adrian, i've edited the post adding the entire exercise, i hope this can be useful. Thank you again

Comment: if you want i can post every step that i followed to reach that matricial equation.

Comment: Yes, that would be good. By the way, the authors are confusing the Lax pair method with the AKNS scheme. They're actually doing the AKNS scheme (with the $X$ and $T$ operators), and calling it the Lax pair. I believe the AKNS scheme is superior, because it's easier to come up with the IST operators than with the Lax pair method.

Comment: Another comment: you're not being asked to verify $\mu^2=1+\lambda^2.$ You're being asked to verify that $(36)$ satisfies $(4)$.

Comment: You've tagged the question as "inverse problems". Please check the tag's wiki to see if this an appropriate tag; I'm not seeing the relevance at the moment.

Comment: @TommiBrander: The AKNS scheme is a method of solution for nonlinear pde's that implements the Inverse Scattering Transform. If you look up the wiki page for Inverse Problems, you will find in the "Non-linear inverse problems" section that the Inverse Scattering Transform method falls into this category. Therefore, I believe the inverse-problem tag is appropriate.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Okay, thanks. I'm not terribly familiar with inverse scattering.

Comment: @TommiBrander: No problem! Inverse scattering is an immensely complex topic, and even my dissertation only touched on one small portion of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of moving pieces, here.

1. Construct $U$ and $V$ with the given expressions, and $u_0(x,t)=e^{2it}.$ Note that $u_x=0$ and $\overline{u}_x=0.$
   \begin{align*}
   U&=\left[\begin{matrix}0 &u\\ \overline{u} &0\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}0 &e^{2it}\\ e^{-2it} &0\end{matrix}\right] \\
   V&=\left[\begin{matrix}|u|^2 &iu_x \\ -i\,\overline{u}_x &-|u|^2\end{matrix}\right]
   =\left[\begin{matrix}1 &0 \\ 0 &-1\end{matrix}\right].
   \end{align*}
2. Next we build the AKNS operators $X$ and $T$ as follows:
   \begin{align*}
   X&=-i\lambda\sigma_3+iU=-i\lambda\left[\begin{matrix}1 &0\\0&-1\end{matrix}\right]+i\left[\begin{matrix}0 &e^{2it}\\ e^{-2it} &0\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}-i\lambda &ie^{2it}\\ ie^{-2it} &i\lambda\end{matrix}\right] \\
   T&=2\lambda X+iV =2\lambda \left[\begin{matrix}-i\lambda &ie^{2it}\\ ie^{-2it} &i\lambda\end{matrix}\right]+i\left[\begin{matrix}1 &0 \\ 0 &-1\end{matrix}\right]
   =\left[\begin{matrix}i-2\lambda^2i &2\lambda i e^{2it} \\ 2\lambda i e^{-2it} &-i+2\lambda^2 i\end{matrix}\right].
   \end{align*}
3. Moving on, we calculate $\Psi_0;$ but it has an annoying term $e^{it\sigma_3}$ in it. That is, we have to exponentiate a matrix. Fortunately, we do not have to go to the trouble of finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and exponentiating the result. Mathematica has the `MatrixExp` function that will do this for us. We get
   $$e^{it\sigma_3}=\left[\begin{matrix}e^{it} &0 \\ 0 &e^{-it}\end{matrix}\right]. $$
   Hence, 
   \begin{align*}
   \Psi_0&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\mu(\mu+\lambda)}}\left[\begin{matrix}e^{it} &0 \\ 0 &e^{-it}\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}e^{i\mu(x+2\lambda t)} &-(\mu+\lambda)e^{-i\mu(x+2\lambda t)}\\(\mu+\lambda)e^{i\mu(x+2\lambda t)}&e^{-i\mu(x+2\lambda t)}\end{matrix}\right] \\
   &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\mu(\mu+\lambda)}}\left[\begin{matrix}e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]} &-(\mu+\lambda)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}\\(\mu+\lambda)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}&e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}\end{matrix}\right].
   \end{align*}
4. The only missing pieces to $(4)$ are $\Psi_x$ and $\Psi_t,$ which for our case, of course, are really $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Psi_0$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi_0,$ respectively. I get
   \begin{align*}
   \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Psi_0&=
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\mu(\mu+\lambda)}}\left[
   \begin{matrix}
   i\mu e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]} 
   &-(\mu+\lambda)(-i\mu)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}\\
   (\mu+\lambda)(i\mu)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &-i\mu e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   \end{matrix}\right] \quad\text{and} \\
   \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi_0&=
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\mu(\mu+\lambda)}}\left[
   \begin{matrix}
    (i(2\mu\lambda+1))e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]} 
   &(\mu+\lambda)(i(2\mu\lambda-1))e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}\\
   (\mu+\lambda)(i(2\mu\lambda-1))e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   & -i(2\mu\lambda+1)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}\end{matrix}\right].
   \end{align*}
   To see that $\Psi_0$ satisfies 
   \begin{align*}
   \Psi_x&=X\Psi \\
   \Psi_t&=T\Psi
   \end{align*}
   should now be a matter of algebra.
5. Speaking of algebra, we can note that if $\Psi\mapsto\alpha\Psi,$ whether $\Psi$ is a solution or not remains unchanged, because $\partial_x(\alpha\Psi)=\alpha\,\partial_x\Psi,$ and $X(\alpha\Psi)=\alpha X\Psi$, and similarly for the $t$ equation. Because M.SE has a rather narrow window for typing up equations, this has a practical value in that we can ignore constants out in front of $\Psi$. That is, we need to check that 
   \begin{align*}
   &\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\mu(\mu+\lambda)}}\left[\begin{matrix}
   i\mu e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]} 
   &-(\mu+\lambda)(-i\mu)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}\\
   (\mu+\lambda)(i\mu)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &-i\mu e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}\end{matrix}\right] \\
   =&\left[\begin{matrix}-i\lambda &ie^{2it}\\ ie^{-2it} &i\lambda\end{matrix}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\mu(\mu+\lambda)}}\left[\begin{matrix}e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]} &-(\mu+\lambda)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}\\(\mu+\lambda)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}&e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}\end{matrix}\right],
   \end{align*}
   or
   \begin{align*}
   &\left[
   \begin{matrix}
   i\mu e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]} 
   &-(\mu+\lambda)(-i\mu)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}\\
   (\mu+\lambda)(i\mu)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &-i\mu e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   \end{matrix}
   \right] \\
   =&\left[
   \begin{matrix}
   -i\lambda &ie^{2it}\\ 
   ie^{-2it} &i\lambda
   \end{matrix}
   \right]
   \left[
   \begin{matrix}
   e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]} &-(\mu+\lambda)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}\\(\mu+\lambda)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]} &e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   \end{matrix}
   \right].
   \end{align*}
   Performing the matrix multiplication on the RHS yields
   \begin{align*}&X\Psi_0= \\ 
   &i\left[
   \begin{matrix}
   -\lambda e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}+(\mu+\lambda)e^{2it}e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &\lambda(\mu+\lambda)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}+e^{2it}e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]} \\
   e^{-2it}e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}+\lambda(\mu+\lambda)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &-(\mu+\lambda)e^{-2it}e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}+\lambda e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   \end{matrix}
   \right]
   \end{align*}
   The $e^{2it}$ and $e^{-2it}$ have the effect of enabling the exponentials to be like terms, with the following spectacular simplification:
   \begin{align*}&X\Psi_0 \\ 
   &=i\left[
   \begin{matrix}
   -\lambda e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}+(\mu+\lambda)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   &\lambda(\mu+\lambda)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}+e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]} \\
   e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}+\lambda(\mu+\lambda)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &-(\mu+\lambda)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}+\lambda e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   \end{matrix}
   \right] \\
   &=i\left[
   \begin{matrix}
   \mu e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   &[\lambda(\mu+\lambda)+1]e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]} \\
   [\lambda(\mu+\lambda)+1]e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &-\mu e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   \end{matrix}
   \right] \\
   &=i\left[
   \begin{matrix}
   \mu e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   &[\lambda\mu+\mu^2]e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]} \\
   [\lambda\mu+\mu^2]e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &-\mu e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   \end{matrix}
   \right] \\
   &=i\mu\left[
   \begin{matrix}
   e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   &(\lambda+\mu)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]} \\
   (\lambda+\mu)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &-e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   \end{matrix}
   \right] \\
   \end{align*}
   At this point, a bit of simplification of $\partial_x\Psi_0$ is in order. At last count, we had 
   \begin{align*}
   &\phantom{=}\partial_x\Psi_0 \\
   &=\left[
   \begin{matrix}
   i\mu e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]} 
   &-(\mu+\lambda)(-i\mu)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}\\
   (\mu+\lambda)(i\mu)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &-i\mu e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   \end{matrix}
   \right] \\
   &=\left[
   \begin{matrix}
   i\mu e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]} 
   &i\mu(\mu+\lambda)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}\\
   i\mu(\mu+\lambda)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &-i\mu e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   \end{matrix}
   \right] \\
   &=i\mu\left[
   \begin{matrix}
    e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]} 
   &(\mu+\lambda)e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}\\
   (\mu+\lambda)e^{i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)-t]}
   &-e^{-i[\mu(x+2\lambda t)+t]}
   \end{matrix}
   \right].
   \end{align*}
   Now you can see that these are, indeed, equal. The $\partial_t \Psi_0=T\Psi_0$ case should work out similarly.

Comment: Honestly, given how unwieldy these equations are becoming, I would simply hand it over to Mathematica.

Comment: it's this the problem, even for me. Ok, thank you!

Comment: That was a tad ungracious of me, my apologies. The fact is, it's a lot of $\LaTeX$ to type up, and I don't have time right now. Perhaps later.

Comment: ok, thank you! i hope you can later. Thanks again

Comment: @AlessandroBile: I've finished up the $\partial_x\Psi_0=X\Psi_0$ case. The other should work out similarly.

Comment: Wow! thank you.. you were very kind!

Comment: @AlessandroBile: You're very welcome! Have a good one!

Comment: Good morning, can i ask you your email to speak faster? I would like to know if your work was even on other aspects of dressing daboux

Comment: @AlessandroBile: I don't imagine we need email to keep the conversation going. M.SE will eventually push this conversation to a private chat. Here is a link to my dissertation, which you can download for free. It's on the eigenvalues of the Manakov system. So, if you do Maxwell's Equations in fiber in cylindrical coordinates, you get nonlinear Schrödinger. The Forward direction of the IST gets you the ZS equations. If, instead, you take birefringence into account in Maxwell's Equations, you get the *coupled* nonlinear Schrödinger equations.

Comment: @AlessandroBile: The forward direction of the IST then gets you the Manakov system, which is a linear system of ODE's. My dissertation was on that. (Link: https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/28169/FinalDraft.pdf). My dissertation had to do with when the eigenvalues of the Manakov system exist, and when they don't. It turns out that eigenvalues of the Manakov system exist if and only if solitons exist, so the existence of the eigenvalues is critical to practical problems.

Comment: @AlessandroBile: To sum up: the IST is an *immensely complicated* transform technique, any step of which is definitely at the research level. It is also an *immensely important* transform technique, as it solves some nonlinear pde's *exactly*.

Comment: @AlessandroBile: By the way, I should ask: have I adequately answered your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was just curios about these things. Have a good day. :)